# WCF-Сервис на IIS 6.0

Tags: c#, wcf

Я выложил свой WCF-Сервис на IIS, сделал консольное приложение - клиента, и при отправке запроса на сервис у меня падает ошибка:

> Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'security.Dll': Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)"

Может я не всю нужную информацию дал, напишите - исправлю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно обойти эту ошибку.

Comment: Нужен [краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода, необходимого для воссоздания проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

`security.dll` - это ваша библиотека или системная? Если вы добавили такую библиотеку в ваш проект - смените ей имя, это имя системной библиотеки и его лучше не занимать.

Если у вас в проекте такой библиотеки в помине нет - значит, речь идет о системной библиотеке. Проверьте, лежит ли она в `%windir%\system32`. Если ее там нет, то узнайте, куда она оттуда делась.

Если у вас такой библиотеки нет, а в `system32` она лежит, приведите хотя бы стекстрейс ошибки.